# How do you break out a list of lists in batch?

Tags: batch

I'm doing a flow that's updating about 600 records and I'm getting timeouts and I think I'm hitting the max 2000 elements. To get around this I'm thinking I want to pass the collection of records to a batch class to chunk out the update and get under the limit. I know that in order to pass the list to apex I need a List<List>. Where I am getting confused is how do I break that into a single list to iterate through in the execute method.

Right now I get a compile error

> Illegal conversion from List<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>> to System.Iterable

```
public class Batch_UpdateSobject implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    public static Integer batchSize = 200; 
    final List<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>> records;

    public Batch_UpdateSobject(List<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>> records)
    {
        this.records = records;
    }

    public Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return records;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> scope) 
    {
        update records;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        //nothing
    }

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void startLoad(List<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>> records)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(new Batch_UpdateSobject(records), batchSize); 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to operate on the entire list object:

```
public class Batch_UpdateSobject implements Database.Batchable<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>>
```

...

```
public Iterable<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    return records;
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>> scope) 
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> allRecords = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
    for(List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> records: scope) 
    {
        allRecords.add(records);
    }
    update allRecords;
}
```

Really, that's a bit more hassle than simply combining the lists before calling the batchable. In your invocable method, just flatten the lists:

```
@InvocableMethod
public static void startLoad(List<List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>> records)
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> allRecords = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
    for(List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> recordList: records) 
    {
        allRecords.addAll(recordList);
    }
    Database.executeBatch(new Batch_UpdateSobject(allRecords), batchSize); 
}
```

And adjust your batchable to accept that type of parameter:

```
final List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> records;

public Batch_UpdateSobject(List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> records)
{
    this.records = records;
}
```

Comment: Database.executeBatch(new Batch_UpdateSobject(recordList), batchSize); Should be Database.executeBatch(new Batch_UpdateSobject(allRecords), batchSize); Right?

Comment: @DanWooding Yeah, copy-paste error, I think :D